# Button not showing on Order view details page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Im trying to add a button to the order view page on the admin, next on the credit memo for example or something similiar, but is not showing the button, and i have no idea how to test it to find the problem.

Here is my code, maybe someone can notice any problem.

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cloud_Magni>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cloud_Magni>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <magni>
                <class>Cloud_Magni_Model</class>
            </magni>
        </models>


        <resources>

            <invoicedocs_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cloud_Magni</module>
                    <class>Cloud_Magni_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </invoicedocs_setup>


            <invoicedocs_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </invoicedocs_write>
            <invoicedocs_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </invoicedocs_read>
        </resources>

        <blocks>
            <magnifi>
                <class>Cloud_Magni_Block</class>
            </magnifi>

        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Cloud_Magni_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <magnifi>
                <class>Cloud_Magni_Helper</class>
            </magnifi>
        </helpers>
        <events>


            <sales_order_invoice_pay>
                <observers>
                    <magni>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>magni/observer</class>
                        <method>createInvoice</method>
                    </magni>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_pay>


            <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <magni>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>magni/observer</class>
                        <method>createCredit</method>
                    </magni>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

View.php:

```
class Cloud_Magni_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View {
    public function  __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_addButton('magni', array(
            $message = "are you sure?",
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Segunda Fatura'),
            'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}','{$this->getUrl('Cloud_Magni')}')"
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now try this.

> app/etc/modules/Cloud_Magni.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Cloud_Magni>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.9</version>
    </Cloud_Magni>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Cloud/Magni/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Cloud_Magni>
      <version>0.0.9</version>
    </Cloud_Magni>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <magni>
        <class>Cloud_Magni_Helper</class>
      </magni>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <magni>
        <class>Cloud_Magni_Block</class>
      </magni>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_view>Cloud_Magni_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Cloud/Magni/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php

```
<?php
class Cloud_Magni_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId    = 'order_id';
        $this->_controller  = 'sales_order';
        $this->_mode        = 'view';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_addButton('magni', array(
            $message = "are you sure123?",
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Segunda Fatura'),
            'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}','{$this->getUrl('Cloud_Magni')}')"
        ));

    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Cloud/Magni/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Cloud_Magni_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Now my side working so please check screen short.

[image]

Comment: What is different about this solution, what was missing?

Comment: IS not working, i put exactlly how you did but doesnt work, could you send me all your files from the extension to compare what is missing?

Comment: now check updated code all files modules.